# How can I Define a function that offers a data and returns True if the data type is string, etc.?

Tags: python

In this function, I need to receive only one parameter in order to determine if the data type is any.

```
def datatype(data, type):
    print(type(data) is type)  # True

datatype("agustin", str) #True
datatype(456.90, int) #False
datatype(456.90, float) #True 
datatype(456.90, bool) #False
```

This function has two parameters, is there a way to do it with only one?

Comment: check isinstance built in python module

Comment: I have this function, but I need to receive only one parameter and w/o compare:
`def comparar_tipo(mi_objeto, tipo):
    if isinstance(mi_objeto, tipo):
        print(mi_objeto, 'es del tipo', tipo)
    return True
    else:
        print(mi_objeto, 'no es del tipo', tipo)
    return False

tipo_de_dato("agustin")`

Comment: if type(myvar) == str : # its is

Comment: Which parameter do you want to receive? Do you want `tipo_de_dato(x)` to determine if `x` has a hard-coded type, or if a hard-coded value has type `x`?

Comment: There's the trivial solution of a parameter that expects a single tuple to be unpacked inside the function: `tipo_de_gato(("agustin", str))`

Answer (score 0):

```
def tipo_de_dato(data, datatype):
    return type(data).__name__ == datatype
    
    
a = tipo_de_dato("agustin", 'str') #True
print(a)

b = tipo_de_dato(456.90, 'int') #False
print(b)

c = tipo_de_dato(456.90, 'float') #True 
print(c)

d = tipo_de_dato(456.90, 'bool') #False
print(d)
```

should work for the given sample

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it:

```
def tipo_de_dato(dato):
    if type(dato) == str or type(dato) == float:
        return True
    else:
        return False
        
    
print(tipo_de_dato("agus")) #True
print(tipo_de_dato(35))
print(tipo_de_dato(345.89))
print(tipo_de_dato(True))
```

Comment: Don't use `==` to compare types; use `isinstance`, which correctly handles subclassing. Also, there's no reason to use an `if` statement and explicit return values. Just use `return ... or ...`.